# Adding VNET Rules to PostgreSQL Server via Azure ARM Template

Tags: postgresql, azure, vnet

I'm writing an Azure Resource Manager template automating the creation of a PostgreSQL database. I have successfully added a firewall rule with the following:

```
{
  "type": "firewallRules"
  "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/', variables('serverName'))]"
    ],
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "name": "[concat(variables('serverName'),'firewall')]",
    "properties": {
      "startIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallStartIpAddress')]",
      "endIpAddress": "[parameters('firewallEndIpAddress')]"
    }
}
```

However, what if I wanted to add a VNET rule instead? There doesn't appear to be any mention of this within the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.dbforpostgresql/servers/firewallrules).

I have researched this and discovered this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/virtualnetworkrules) but it is in regards to the 'Microsoft.Sql' resource, not the 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL' resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the API for PostgreSQL : [Virtual Network Rules - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/postgresql/virtualnetworkrules/createorupdate) , it seems MS missed it in the template.

I have tried the template like the template for sql below, but it doesn't work.

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/virtualNetworkRules",
  "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
  "properties": {
    "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "string",
    "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": boolean
  }
}
```

**Update**:

Per my test, after setting vnet rule of a SQL DB in the portal, I can find it via **Azure Resource Explorer** (you could access it in resource.azure.com), please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

AFAIK, azure database for PostgreSQL supports API, azure CLI, azure portal to set vnet rule.

But After setting it in the portal, I could **not** find it in the **resource explorer** and **Automation script**.

[image]

So I think postgresql does **not** support ARM template. If you want to improve the azure db for postgresql, you could post your idea in the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/597976-azure-database-for-postgresql).

Besides, I find an idea of [ARM Template for MySQL](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/597982-azure-database-for-mysql/suggestions/19581562-arm-template-for-mysql), it is supported now. If you post it, I think it will be supported in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no luck here. 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/servers/virtualNetworkRules' is not accepted

Comment: @Xenidious Yes, I test it and have the same result of you, also, I set the vnet rule in the portal and check it in the azure resource explorer, I could not find it. It seems postpresql does not support arm template. But there is an API, it is strange.